# Не могу установить WebPack. Git bash выдает ошибку

Tags: webpack

Webpack не ставится, не совсем понимаю почему. Пишет ошибки по путям к файлам

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './bar.js'
```

Уже раз 100 поменял и названия файлов и пути к ним. Все равно проблемы  Кто может подсказать? Запускаю через команду `npx webpack`

Это код скрипта.

```
const myModule = require('./bar.js'); 

const myModuleInstance = new myModule();

myModuleInstance.hello();
myModuleInstance.goodbye();
```

Это код файла `Bar`

```
function myModule() {
    this.hello = function() {
        console.log('hello');
    };
    
    this.goodbye = function() {
        console.log('bye!');
    };
}

module.exports = myModule;
```

Comment: А где тут установка webpack?

Comment: когда запускаю Git Bash в той папке и ввожу "npx webpack", то выдает ошибку. Файлы частично скачиваются, но не в полном объеме

Comment: 1. `npx webpack` это не установка. 2. Приведите ошибку. Хрустальные шары не работают.